# Highlight text in two textboxes at the same time

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

in order to select text in a textbox you need to focus into it.
The problem is, after focusing and selecting the second textbox, it deselects the text in the first textbox.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please explain why you wish such functionality, and maybe we can find an alternative.

Comment: The program plays an audio of selected text in two languages, hence two textboxes (one for each language)

Comment: Why not have something like an apply selection per text box which moves this to a selected label/secondary text box?

Comment: Thanks. But the requirement is to have the text in read only textboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `HideSelection` property of the `TextBox` to `false`.

```
myTextBox.HideSelection = false;
```

Of cause you can do it in the properties window as well (in the `Behavior` section).